# Set tangle-mode 444 for all source blocks in buffer

Tags: org-mode, tangle

How can I tangle all source blocks write protected? The first line of this
example is ignored instead of being applied to all blocks as expected:

```
    #+PROPERTY: header-args:conf :comments link :tangle-mode (identity #o444)

    * Fail: File is NOT write-protected
    #+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle .NotWorkingReadOnlyDotFile
    echo helloHello
    #+END_SRC

    * Pass: File IS write-protected
    #+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle .WorkingReadOnlyDotFile :tangle-mode (identity #o444)
    echo helloHello
    #+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `header-args:conf` to set options for `conf` blocks, for all `sh` blocks, use

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sh :tangle-mode (identity #o444)
```

for all blocks, use

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle-mode (identity #o444)
```

See also [`(info "(org) Header arguments in Org mode properties")`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties.html).